# How do I create a custom marker/style with a text label in Drupal using Openlayers 7.x-3x

Tags: drupal, openlayers-3

This question is specifically about Drupal Openlayers **7.x-3.x**.

In the older version 7.x-**2.x** adding a custom marker style with label was very simple, and could even be done in the UI. A Token was even provided for you to use the Node's title.  This functionality does not exist in the UI 7.x-**3.x**.

How do I accomplish the goal of creating a custom marker style *with a text label* in Openlayers 7.x-3.x?

Comment: I really did not like the complexity of openlayers, so created my own mapping module called [Goomap](https://www.drupal.org/project/goomap). It may interest you as an alternative to openlayers